How do I make sure a garden hose doesn't leak?
Whenever I connect a garden hose to the water spout, it leaks from that connection. How can i stop that from happening? I can tell that it isn't connected to the age of the hose, as it even happens with a brand new hose.

If the connection leaks with every hose, even a brand new hose, then you might need to replace the spout. But first, double check that it's not simply the case that the rubber grommet has fallen out of the hose fitting - it's easy to miss and will cause a poor seal at the hose bibb.

It depends.
Try to tight the screw (which may be on the side or it is the entire fitting, depending on the model), or replace the o-ring. Cold and hot may just remove most of elastic properties of the o-ring.
Be sure both fittings are clean. Sand may ruin it, and if so, you need to replace them. Also tap fittings may be of different type, and if you attached it to the wrong one, you may ruined the fitting. Note: American are different to European, and both have two different fittings for gardens and for inside fittings. The quick fittings ("Gardena" style, not invented by Gardena) are more standardized, but still: they may require the right size and width of hose, and there are few different sizes (but it should be obvious, the other 4 have the same size, so much easier to do it wrongly).
Else: remove the fitting, check it carefully and check the hose (again: cold and hot may remove some elastic properties, and the hose may get some cracks if it was too tight).
You may want to replace the fittings, and try later with the old one.
Some cheap fittings are much worse then others (it is really random), so maybe it is a bad fitting, or bad design, or bad quality control (so not within standard).

You can try thread tape. Wrapping it around the threads on your hose should prevent any leakage.
